# Android MultiChoiceAdapter Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am doing MultiChoiceAdapter with Listview.But when i Run then crashed.What is Error please help me.

May be problem this line:
    CheckedTextView checkedView=(CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

```
04-03 17:15:32.709: E/Trace(5044): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-03 17:15:33.409: D/dalvikvm(5044): GC_CONCURRENT freed 39K, 7% free 2793K/2976K, paused 20ms+12ms, total 84ms
04-03 17:15:33.529: D/AndroidRuntime(5044): Shutting down VM
04-03 17:15:33.529: W/dalvikvm(5044): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.CheckBox cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckedTextView
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at com.example.ppp.MainActivity$MyArrayAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:149)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-03 17:15:33.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5044):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

#### MainAcivity:

```
   package com.example.ppp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView myListView;
    Button getResult;
    private ArrayList<String> dayOfWeekList=new ArrayList<String>();
    private void initDayOfWeekList(){
        dayOfWeekList.add("sunday");
        dayOfWeekList.add("Monday");
        dayOfWeekList.add("Tuesday");
        dayOfWeekList.add("Wednesday");
        dayOfWeekList.add("Fridayday");
        dayOfWeekList.add("sunday");
        dayOfWeekList.add("satday");

    }
    MyArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getResult=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnResult);
        initDayOfWeekList();
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

          adapter=new MyArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.adapter_layout, R.id.checkBox1
            , dayOfWeekList);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {

                adapter.toggleChecked(position);

            }


        });

        getResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String res="";

                ArrayList<String> resultList=adapter.getCheckedItem();
                for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
                res+=String.valueOf(resultList.get(i))+"\n";    
                adapter.getCheckedPosition().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });




    }







    private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked=new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                myChecked.put(i, false);
            }

        }
        public void toggleChecked(int position) {
                if(myChecked.get(position)){
                    myChecked.put(position, false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    myChecked.put(position, true);
                }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public ArrayList<Integer>  getCheckedPosition() {
            ArrayList<Integer> CheckedPosition=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++) {
                if(myChecked.get(i)){
                    (CheckedPosition).add(i);
                }

            }
            return CheckedPosition;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItem() {
            ArrayList<String> CheckedItem=new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++) {
                if(myChecked.get(i)){
                    (CheckedItem).add(dayOfWeekList.get(i));
                }

            }
            return CheckedItem;

        }

       @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View view=convertView;
           if(view==null){
                LayoutInflater inflat=getLayoutInflater();
                view=inflat.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, parent,false);
           }
          CheckedTextView checkedView=(CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
          checkedView.setText(dayOfWeekList.get(position));

          Boolean checked=myChecked.get(position);
          if(checked!=null){
              checkedView.setChecked(checked);
          }


        return view;
    }

    }



}
```

#### adapter_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because it is a checkbox, not a checkedtextview. either declare a checkedtextview in the layout or cast as a checkbox in java.

Comment: (and yes, posting the code (xml layout and adapter definition) would be useful. If you look at a few other android questions, you'll see that posting both the code and the stacktrace are usually prerequisite to getting your problem solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your adapter_layout does not have a `CheckedTextView` - `checkBox1` is a `CheckBox` (which is a `TextView`). You should do this:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

Also, your activity_main layout does not have a listView1 - but it looks like you may have pasted the same layout twice.